# Migrate Ubuntu to bigger HDD

Tags: linux, ubuntu, migration, ddrescue

I have a multi-boot system and want to push my Ubuntu installation to a bigger partition on the **same** hdd, because I want the system to have more memory available.

What I know so far is I can clone with `ddrescue` using following command.

```
sudo ddrescue -v --force /dev/sda_old /dev/sda_new
```

Is that all I have to consider? Does `ddrescue` do the filesystem formatting or do I have to do it manually?

Of course after the whole process I have to set my bootloader with

```
sudo grub-mkconfig    # for creating the grub config file
sudo update-grub      # for saving the new config file
```

Comment: Note that using this approach the partition table of the new disk will be a clone of the partition of the old disk and you'll have adjust that and resize the partitions. Maybe an easier approach would be to use GParted to copy the disk. SystemRescueCD has a lot of helpful tools including GParted.

Comment: I don't want to change the disk, just the partition on the same disk. But thanks, I'm going to consider this in future.

Comment: So you already have two partitions, one that currently holds your Ubuntu installation and one larger one that you want to move it to?

Comment: Yes. I updated the question to make this clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Remember this, it's just a clone of the old data, so, in the case that you want to use that disk in another PC, all the dynamic modules and configurations are attached to the old system. That is, the drivers, configurations of devices and etc.

Comment: Of course, thank you. But I think I have an easier scenario here and don't have to consider these dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you don't have to clone your partition (you could clone it on *another* disk to backup your data if something goes wrong, that's all); what I would do if I were you would just to use a live CD or USB-key with Gparted installed, and resize the partitions on the HDD as desired. Therefore you won't need to clone, update grub and so one...